# Join 2 columns from Table 1(foreign key) to Table 2(primary key) - How to avoid JOIN BUFFER?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

```
Schema:
CALL (ID,USER_ID(Foreign key),SP_USER_ID(Foreign key))
USER (ID,NAME)
```

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT u.name, 
       v.name 
FROM   call c 
       INNER JOIN USER u 
               ON c.user_id = u.id 
       INNER JOIN USER v 
               ON c.sp_user_id = v.id
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT u.name 
FROM   call c 
       INNER JOIN USER u 
               ON c.user_id = u.id
```

Query 2 works fine and the results come quickly too.

But query 1 takes a lot of time and sometimes MySQL client crashes(seeing explain plan,it shows "JOIN BUFFER" for one of the USER tables).

"where" condition on SP_USER_ID or USER_ID somewhat gives the results quickly but it is not in the acceptable range."where" condition on other columns does not have any effect.

How to avoid JOIN BUFFER to get faster results in this case and get the desired results either by joins or some other way?

Comment: You have three tables or two tables ? Do you have another table for Super_User ?

Comment: No.Only 2 tables - CALL and USER.USER table has all the user information.USER_ID in CALL is like the customer's id and SP_USER_ID in CALL is like the person's id who is servicing/attending to that customer.Now,I need to join with USER table to get the name of both USER_ID and SP_USER_ID.

Answer (score 1):

Hope there's an index over `USER_ID` column, and not over `SP_USER_ID` column. Hence it chooses for `JOIN BUFFER`.

As per docs, A `JOIN BUFFER` is used only when the join is of type `ALL` or `index` (in other words, when no possible keys can be used).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/join-buffer-size.html

Comment: I have indexes on both USER_ID and SP_USER_ID.Even having indexes on these 2 columns seems not to help me.